# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in node js

Tags: node.js, angular, get

I am getting this error only when I call get method (Not every time).

Here is my node function which returns me a response.

```
exports.GetDepartmentList = function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./api/tempFiles/department.json', 'utf8', function (err,response) {
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            data: JSON.parse(response)
        });
        return res.json();
        dbConn.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        });
        return res.json();
        dbConn.close();
    });
};
```

I already checked all the StackOverflow's questions but none of them are helpful for solving my problem.

Comment: Why write `return res.json();` ? and also `dbConn.close();` after it, as return terminates the function `dbConn.close();` will never be called. Use either `send` or `json` methods of `res` not both

Comment: I removed it but its not working. Same error occurred.@Dhyey

Comment: pls edit the ques with updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occured when you send multiple responses to your client side.

I think you should try with something like this (without catch)

```
exports.GetDepartmentList = function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./api/tempFiles/department.json', 'utf8', function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: err.message
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                data: JSON.parse(response)
            });
        }
        dbConn.close(); // Really usefull ?
    });
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ! But can you explain why i shouldn't use catch ??

Comment: Maybe you can use catch, but I think you dont need to, because an error is already catched on your callback function (err, response)